# Best way to implement business logic rules in tastypie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

The frontend of this project will have business rules built in using JS but the backend of this app which is built in tastypie will enforce these rules. Putting rules in models seems a bit messy and it would be nice to have the rules somewhere in each `ModelResource` class.

Which methods should I override and how should I best report restrictions and exceptions back?

The type of logic will be along the lines of

```
if field_x = 5 and request.user != 2:
    complain and don't process request
    send back error
```

The `hydrate` method looks like a good place to do checking but I'm not certain how I'd raise exceptions properly and explain via those exceptions what went wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reading through the documentation in alphabetical order and finally came across: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html

Comment: Yes, you could define custom exceptions, raise them when you find invalid data, catch them in wrap_view to build proper API response based on them and send back to the user.